# How to load a GLTF asset without ron file

Tags: rust, amethyst

I want to load a gltf file without ron files. I have followed their [official example for gltf](https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst/blob/master/examples/gltf/main.rs). But they are loading the GLTF file from a ron file in that example. How to change this example to load gltf without a ron file?